# Colouring JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, colors, jcombobox

Dumb question: I am trying to colour a JComboBox - my ComboBoxRenderer getListCellRendererComponent method sometimes gets control and works fine - at other times the JComboBox is just white. This problem seems to be partly affected by whether the combobox has the focus, but my method never seems to have the boolean cellHasFocus on - even when the JComboBox as a whole seems to function as though it has focus!

One idea I had was to create my own ComboBox class - or can I create a UI class to handle the paint function?  Nothing I've tried seems to work - help would be appreciated!

Comment: The `ListCellRenderer` should be fine. You're going to need to share code...Do you only want to color the list portion or the field portion as well?

Comment: Thanks, @MadProgrammer!  I checked and I don't have a field portion - I just have two rows, and toggle between them.  So I would like to have both rows coloured when the JComboBox has focus, and white when it hasn't.  If a row is selected as well, it would be nice if it had another colour, but this isn't essential.  As I said, the ListCellRenderer *never* seems to see cellHasFocus as true.   So, I don't know whether I should be working with the JComboBox itself, or with the JComboBoxUI. Can you give some advice?  TIA

Comment: Do you have some sample code (of what you have), I'm having trouble getting my head around it

Comment: Hi @MadProgrammer!  If I just create a new (no field) JComboBox, it is coloured white.  If I add the statement cBox.setUI(new BasicComboBoxUI()); the JComboBox is white if it doesn't have focus, blue if it does, and only actually shows the colours I specified in my getListCellRendererComponent method when I select one of the rows using the mouse (not with up & down arrows).  It then goes back to blue after selection.  My question is: how do I control these colours - in particular the blue as I have no idea where (or why) this is being generated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found a solution (paintComponent) in another post about JComboBox.  However, the text resulting from doing drawString in paintComponent looks a bit "shaky" (compared with, say, JList scrolling display), so it's not a great solution - anyone know why this should be and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Sorry, brain fried. I would avoid trying to implement your own ComboBoxUI, to many issues.  As to the text rendering, that's probably got a lot to do with the how the LabelUI works.  I tend to "cheat", creating a instance of a `JLabel`, setting it's required bounds to what I need and then using the `Graphics` object, `paint` it ;)

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, and sorry, I didn't see this post before!  I realized that I had the JLabel code already in my getListCellRendererComponent method, but for some reason the colours weren't being handled correctly, so I have added some colour logic to a paintComponent method (plus another JLabel!) in a class called MyComboBox.  The colours are now just about as good as I can get them (and the text looks great)!  One last strange thing is that the cellHasFocus boolean in the getListCellRendererComponent method never seems to be true, no matter what I try! Anyway, thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks, @Iron-Fede, I didn't realize that question was still outstanding!  :-)  My ComboBox logic seems to be working in the current code, and I don't seem to be using drawString, so I guess I found a different technique that works better.  But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

in my class i use this : (`UIManager`)

```
UIManager.put("ComboBox.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.lightGray));
    UIManager.put("JTextField.background", new ColorUIResource(Color.lightGray));
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionBackground", new ColorUIResource(Color.green));
    UIManager.put("ComboBox.selectionForeground", new ColorUIResource(Color.RED));
```